# Finding an annotation in a list

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

In my code, I may have annotation defined on methods or fields so what I'm doing is checking both the methods and fields in the class and I store all annotations in a separate list.

Then later I have a method called getAnnotation.

```
Annotation getAnnotation(Class annotationClass) {
    for (Annotation annotation : annotations) {
        if (annotation.getClass().equals(annotationClass)) {
            return annotation;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

And I call it like this:

```
Annotation annotation = getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class);
```

The problem is that the getAnnotation method does not match up the class names. When I debug I see that the annotations are showing as proxy objects. How can I find the specific annotation that I want in this case?

TIA

I define the map like this:

```
Map<Class<? extends Annotation>, Annotation> annotations = new HashMap<Class<? extends Annotation>, Annotation>(4);
```

I populated the Map like this:

```
Annotation[] annotations = method.getAnnotations();
for (Annotation annotation : annotations) {
  annotations.put(annotation.getClass(), annotation);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yay! I figured it out.  The Annotation object has an "annotationType()" method to return the real class name.

So the code for anyone interested would look like this:

Map, Annotation> annotations = new HashMap, Annotation>(4);

```
Annotation[] annos = method.getAnnotations();
for (Annotation anno : annos) {
    annotations.put(anno.annotationType(), annotation);
}
```

Then the class matching works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You'd better populate a `Map<Class<? extends Annotation>, Annotation>` - that way the lookup will be O(1), and you won't care if its a proxy or not.

Comment: Nice idea. Now I see proxys on both keySet and values. :(

Comment: Ok check edits. I think it's because I get these annotations from reflection so they are proxied somehow,

Comment: well, I don't think you can make a proxy of `Class`. It's `final`. How do you tell it's a proxy?

Comment: When I debug the class names look like this: $Proxy3 instead of the actual class name.